# fastest way to filter a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, numba

I am trying to filter a numpy array of array, I have done a function like the following:

```
@nb.njit
def numpy_filter (npX):
    n = np.full (npX.shape[0], True)

    for npo_index in range(npX.shape[0]):
        n[npo_index] = npX[npo_index][0] < 2000 and npX[npo_index][1] < 4000 and npX[npo_index][2] < 5000

    return npX[n]
```

It took 1.75s (numba njit mode) for len of array = 600K , while it only take < 0.5s for list [x for x in obj1 if x[0] < 2000 and x[1] < 4000 and x[2] < 5000]

Is there any better implementation could have a filtering function that could make it run faster?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to filter? There are lots of ways to extract information from a numpy array but it depends on what you are trying to do? If you are using lists of 1D numpy arrays you really should combine them into a 2D array.

Comment: With a `numpy` array `a` of shape (600000,3) of randint(0,10000). `a[(a < np.array([2000,4000,5000])).all(1)]` *100 loops, best of 5: 19 ms per loop*

Comment: I'm going to repeat what's already been said.  If you find yourself iterating through a numpy array, then you probably shouldn't be using numpy in the first place.

Comment: Did you warm up the jitted function? I got with `@njit` *100 loops, best of 5: 3.65 ms per loop*, `list comprehension` *1 loop, best of 5: 375 ms per loop*, `pure numpy` *100 loops, best of 5: 19 ms per loop* with two cores on google colab. ~100x speed up to `python` with `numba`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, you are right, I did not have it warmed up.... after warmed up, it get down to 0.07s ish. this is very cool... and now. I am needing to sort out the quickest way to merge the result

Comment: `list comprehension` gets much faster when the numpy array is converted to python ints *10 loops, best of 5: 43.1 ms per loop*. Similar results for floats.

Comment: @FrankYellin, if not using numpy, then what is the best way to speed it up?

Comment: Sorry.  You misunderstood my comment.  I agree with all the solutions given by others so far.  If you find yourself iterating through a numpy array, you should either not be using numpy, or you should find a way to avoid iteration.

Comment: It is likely unable to avoid the iteration as after the filtering, the result will be used for some other calculation that would use then as parameters. Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Generally with Pandas/NumPy arrays, you'll get the best performance if you

- avoid iterating over the array
- only create soft copies or views of the base array
- create a minimal number of intermediate Python objects

Pandas is probably your friend here, allowing you to create a view of the backing NumPy arrays and operate on the rows of each via a shared index

#### starting data

This creates a random array of the same shape as your source data, with values range from 0-10000

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.random.rand(600000, 3) * 10000
>>> arr
array([[8079.54193993,  925.74430028, 2031.45569251],
       [8232.74161149, 2347.42814063, 7571.21287502],
       [7435.52165567,  756.74380534, 1023.12181186],
       ...,
       [2176.36643662, 5374.36584708,  637.43482263],
       [2645.0737415 , 9059.42475818, 3913.32941652],
       [3626.54923011, 1494.57126083, 6121.65034039]])
```

#### create a Pandas DataFrame

This creates view over your source data so you can work with all the rows together using a shared index

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
>>> df
                  0            1            2
0       8079.541940   925.744300  2031.455693
1       8232.741611  2347.428141  7571.212875
2       7435.521656   756.743805  1023.121812
3       4423.799649  2256.125276  7591.732828
4       6892.019075  3170.699818  1625.226953
...             ...          ...          ...
599995   642.104686  3164.107206  9508.818253
599996   102.819102  3068.249711  1299.341425
599997  2176.366437  5374.365847   637.434823
599998  2645.073741  9059.424758  3913.329417
599999  3626.549230  1494.571261  6121.650340

[600000 rows x 3 columns]
```

#### filter

This gets a filtered view of the index for each columns and uses the combined result filter the DataFrame

```py
>>> df[(df[0] < 2000) & (df[1] < 4000) & (df[2] < 5000)]
                  0            1            2
35      1829.777633  1333.083450  1928.982210
38       653.584288  3129.089395  4753.734920
71      1354.736876   279.202816     5.793797
97      1381.531847   551.465381  3767.436640
115      183.112455  1573.272310  1973.143995
...             ...          ...          ...
599963  1895.537096  1695.569792  1866.575164
599970  1061.011239    51.534961  1014.290040
599988  1780.535714  2311.671494  1012.828410
599994   878.643910   352.858091  3014.505666
599996   102.819102  3068.249711  1299.341425

[24067 rows x 3 columns]
```

benchmark maybe to follow, but it's very fast

Comment: I have got 0.18s... slower than numpy, but faster than list

Comment: I have also marked as in nb.njit mode, but got a little bit slower (0.22s)

Comment: anecdotally, and it's been a minute since I tried anything with numba (though it was spectacularly fast for some tests) .. but I believe it tends to suffer and often have worse performance when working with any non-numpy objects due to some copying(?)

Comment: more specifically, always set `nopython=True` and no Pandas allowed!

Answer (score 1):

The jit function has not been warmed up, after the first run, the result shows it only takes 0.07s to finish the task.

Comment: makes sense; it's probably good to point to the docs here (as it's not otherwise clear that you mean the _numba JIT cache_) and also see if [Michael's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69291542/fastest-way-to-filter-a-2d-numpy-array/69291684?noredirect=1#comment122471016_69291542) is even faster (which should be compilable as it's all-NumPy)

Comment: I am sure that it is not the result from the cache..

Comment: ah, the cache of compiled snippets, not results (otherwise you could of course cheat a benchmark with something like [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache))

Answer (score 0):

Make your jit function return only the mask `n`, dont send `npX[n]`.
Since jit compiler can not fix the the return size of filtered array there is chance it will slow down.

Do the filtering i.e. `npX[n]` outside jit function. That should speed up.

Also to get actual time better add signature with decorater, this will force eager compilation.

The optimization way in both numpy and numba are different so you always experiment which will be faster. But when speed is almost same you can add parallel option which will make it more faster(I guess you already know that)